# cross browser custom shape with css

Tags: css

hello i am trying to make a custom shape and insert an image inside it. Below is the css i have written so far and it only works on chrome browser , how do i make make it work on all browser

```
.shape-custom{
    width:62vw;
    height:600px;
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    -webkit-shape-outside:polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    shape-margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(74, 161, 255);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check "caniuse.com", before trying to use *experimental* styles for production.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes

Comment: thank you,  it seems that property is not supported in other browsers, can u suggest an alternative for such case, how would you make custom shape like avove

Comment: I think you could use svg.

Comment: Hope fully you will get answer and coding solution from this tutorial link
http://tutorialzine.com/2017/03/css-triangles-without-hacks/

Comment: @Momin still - support for clip-path is not that great either.

Comment: you can also check https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/ - if that fits your requirement